# Why does CDK complain about missing public subnet groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

This is my current CDK stack:

```
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "vpc-staging", {
  maxAzs: 1,
  enableDnsHostnames: true,
  enableDnsSupport: true,
  cidr: '10.10.0.0/16',
  subnetConfiguration: []
});

const publicSubnet = new ec2.Subnet(this, 'public-subnet', {
  cidrBlock: '10.10.10.0/24',
  vpcId: vpc.vpcId,
  mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
})
```

To the above I am trying to add an ECS cluster like so:

```
const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'EcsCluster', { vpc });
cluster.addCapacity('DefaultAutoScalingGroup', {
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO)
})
```

When running `cdk diff` this is the error that I get:

```
(node:48942) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
/Users/me/src/wow/aws/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.js:201

throw new Error(`There are no '${subnetType}' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: ${availableTypes}`);
^

Error: There are no 'Public' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types:
```

What is it that that I am missing from my config?

Answer (score 1):

`mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true` is **not sufficient** for a subnet to be considered `Public`.

You also need an `Internet Gateway` which is **attached** to your VPC. In addition, **route tables** should be setup to route internet traffic `0.0.0.0/0` to the gateway.

General information about VPC, public and private subnets is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `mapPublicIpOnLaunch` parameter has a default set to `true`, so you could simply not set any subnet at all by simply removing the `subnetConfiguration` line from the vpc and deleting the subnet object to leave the default creation.

If you really want to set them, add `subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC` to your subnet.

Also, I think it's better if you keep the subnet config on the vpc construct to wire everything on the vpc creation:

```js
 const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "vpc-staging", {
    maxAzs: 1,
    enableDnsHostnames: true,
    enableDnsSupport: true,
    cidr: '10.10.0.0/16',
    subnetConfiguration: [
       {
        cidrMask: 24,   // this is optional as it divides equally if not set
        name: 'public-subnet',
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
      },
      {
        cidrMask: 24,
        name: 'private-subnet',
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE,
      },
    ...
  ]
});
```

Also, I'm not 100% sure, but this code might fail because ECS need at least two availability zones to work.